# Curl with PHP to scrape a website not working

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to call Citi Bank's open API (https://developer.citi.com/) and this require me to scrape the screen to allow the user to login with his username and password.

This works if I simply put this URL with parameters in the browser.

```
https://sandbox.apihub.citi.com/gcb/api/authCode/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<my_client_id>&scope=pay_with_points&countryCode=SG&businessCode=GCB&locale=en_SG&state=12093&redirect_uri=<my_callback>
```

However, when I attempt to make the same call from my PHP codes with curl, it returns status code of 503.

```
<?php

$header = array();
$header[] = 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1';
$header[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8';
$header[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br';
$header[] = 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ja;q=0.6,zh-CN;q=0.4,zh;q=0.2,zh-TW;q=0.2,th;q=0.2';

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://sandbox.apihub.citi.com/gcb/api/authCode/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<my_client_id>=pay_with_points&countryCode=SG&businessCode=GCB&locale=en_SG&state=12093&redirect_uri=<my_callback_url>');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

I have attempted to change my request headers so that it is just like how it would look if I had entered it as a URL in my browser.

I must have missed out something that I need to configure in curl.

Would anyone have some idea? Thank you!

Comment: whats with `redirect_uri=<my_callback_url>`?

Comment: and `<my_client_id>`?

Comment: It's my callback URL. The authorize api will call back to what I state here, for example http://www.myurl.com/bank/hello.php.

Comment: my_client_id is the api key given to me by citi.

Comment: did your read the documentation, i don't think you need those headers

Comment: I did it without headers too, and it didn't work either. My strategy has been to make the curl as close as possible to executing in the browser but it seemed that I was still missing something.

Answer (score 2):

The issue might be due to https. There are few options available.

**1.** You can download the  [https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem](https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem) file and save it and then add this option

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/path/to/cacert.pem");
```

**2.** You can download the certificate from the browser by going to that site and do the same as above. You might run into problems if they change their certificates, need to confirm with them.

**3.** This is not recommended but can be used temporarily for debugging purposes to find out, if this is the actual problem. It introduces MIMT attacks.

```
//Only use for debugging purposes.
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks Kamal. I realized that when viewed in a browser, the page redirects and drops a cookie before redirecting to the next page. If I paste the cookie and curl with it, it works. But the page only generates the HTML portion. Parts that get written using JavaScript doesn't come up. I figured perhaps curl isn't the correct solution for this. I should have just done a page redirect. The downside is that the user sees my client_id. I need to think if it actually matters that my client_id isn't a secret.

Answer (score -1):

You can use header('location: '.$url);